# Canny edge detection does not detect 100% horizontal/un-rotated lines

Tags: java, opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

Is the Canny edge detection supposed to **not** detect *pure, non-rotated* horizontal lines?

These are the input images:

**Left:** 100% horizontal (non-rotated) non-blurry lines
**Right:** the same image 1° rotated

[image: Pure horizontal lines, input image]
[image: Horizontal lines 1° rotated, input image]

The corresponding output "edges" images:

[image: Pure horizontal lines, output image]
[image: Horizontal lines 1° rotated, output image]

(Images scaled here 2x with no smoothing for better judging.)

The images were processed with thresholds low=250x0.66 and high=250x1.33 and kernel size k=3.

While the ladder image generated quiet satisfying results, the former image does not.

The images were not further pre-processed at the moment, what you see is what's going into Canny.

I created the first image as test data. It might be a constructed case, although such lines might occur in real world scenarios.

MCVE:

```
public class q58884116 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.load(new File(Paths.get("target", "classes", "libopencv_java412.so").toString()).getAbsolutePath());

        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        File outFile = new File(args[1]);

        Mat imageColor = Imgcodecs.imread(inFile.getAbsolutePath(), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
        Mat patternProbeImage = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(imageColor, patternProbeImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        Mat edges = new Mat();
        // Value determined from histogram in Gimp.
        Imgproc.Canny(patternProbeImage, edges, 250 * 0.66, 250 * 1.33, 3, true);

        Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile.getAbsolutePath(), edges);
    }
}
```

The input image (unscaled): [input.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSpFt.png)

- Compiled from Git
- OpenCV 4.1.2
- cmake 3.7.2
- gcc 6.3.0
- openjdk 1.8.0_232
- Using the Java library.

The build steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv/
$ git checkout 4.1.2
$ cd cmake/
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/opencv" ..
$ make -j4
$ make install
```

---

I must admit, I'm not familiar with the theories behind Canny or even computer vision in general. I'm just getting started with it. Although I can imagine this might be caused by the row of zeros of the Gy matrix used by the [Sobel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) (which was mentioned in Canny function articles).

If this is indeed a limitation of Canny, what are usual approaches to handle such scenarios (in short)?

---

I approached this empirically: I've created a white to black gradient image
with a black grating pattern on top of it. The grating shall represent the
lines of the original test image on top of different backgrounds.

This is our input image:

[image: Gradient with grating (cropped preview)]

(Cropped and resized for prettier post, [download original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jilSB.png).)

The MCVE is extended to generate edges for a variety of threshold ranges (not
every possible combination there is, but a fair amount):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255 - 50; i++) {
    Mat edges = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(patternProbeImage, edges, i, i + 50, 3, true);

    Imgcodecs.imwrite(getOutputFile(outFile, "lb-0-" + String.format("%03d", i)).getAbsolutePath(), edges);
}
```

We can then inspect the generated edges.

With this one liner a mosaic (sprite) of all images was generated for easier
inspection:

```
$ convert gradient-grating.out.lb-0-*.png +append  gradient-grating.out.lb.png
```

This is the result:

[image: Edge image mosaic of the above input image]

As one can see, Canny was unable to detect more and more edges on the minimum
value side (top) with increasing lower thresholds. I expected this. Though on the maximum value side, Canny was *never* able to detect edges, no matter what thresholds were given.

Comment: Canny is mainly used for *edge* detection by determining where the brightness of the image changes drastically. Its used to extract the structure of objects in an image. Essentially an edge in computer vision is a sudden pixel change. It may be due to your thresholds. I'm getting correct results with `low=100` and `high=200`. Alternative approaches to detecting lines are to use `HoughLinesP` or to construct a horizontal kernel and use morphology

Comment: I just tried this in Python and it worked. Previously, I have worked with OpenCV in Java, and I found that the Canny filter does not behave the same way in OpenCV/Python as it does in OpenCV/Java.

Comment: Valuable comment Stephen. nathancy, I tried it with other thresholds before and now with your values - no success.

Comment: With my Java Opencv (version 3.3) I get similar outputs with both images, although they are not as good as your output for second image but definitely better than first one. With my c++ Opencv (version 4.0) my results are identical to yours. I wonder what version @StephenMeschke tested with. I will investigate further later.

Comment: What is the signifiance of the high threshold `250 x 1.66`, which is out of the gray range ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, well spotted. This is an artifact from the original code that made it through to the MCVE. Though it makes no difference, even with 160 x 0.66 and 160 x 1.33 (160 is the average value) or a black and white image (threshold) image and 0, 255 Canny fails the same way.

Comment: And what's the effect of the low threshold ?

Comment: I'm currently exploring a similar issue for horizontal lines, and discovered through looking at a HLS conversion that there were some artifacts along the line that caused my expected edge to disappear. May be a cause for others with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image and then opening the image file directly.  It may simply be an issue with how the plotter is rendering the image.

I had the same issue myself, but solved it.  I was viewing my edge image through a jupyter notebook, using matplotlib.  The 100% horizontal edges would not render when displayed inside the notebook.  But when I saved it to png and opened the image file directly, the horizontal edges were in fact there.